# read file by line and store in database

Tags: java, database, file

I have a file like this :

```
1
00:00:00,535 --> 00:00:02,462
Je suis professeur d'informatique et
d'ingéniérie informatique

2
00:00:02,462 --> 00:00:04,389
à Carnegie Mellon,

3
00:00:04,389 --> 00:00:06,318
et mes recherches se concentrent sur
l'utilisabilité de la vie privée
```

The file is too long, about 600 subtitles, each subtitle has its 'ID' (like 1, 2, 3...), its 'timecode' (like 00:00:02,462 --> 00:00:04,389 ...), its 'subtitle_line1' (like "Je suis professeur d'informatique et" ...) and its subtitle_line2 (like "d'ingéniérie informatique" ..., but not all; there are some subtitles that have just 'subtitle_line1' like the subtitle of ID=2 for example).

I need to read it and store it in a database. For that, I create a database whose schema like :

subtitle (id, timecode, subtitle_line1, subtitle_line2)

And i create a java bean Subtitle.java like this :

```
public class Subtitle {
private String subtitleId;
private String timeCode;
private String originalSubtitleLine1;
private String originalSubtitleLine2;

public String getSubtitleId() {
    return subtitleId;
}

public void setSubtitleId(String subtitleId) {
    this.subtitleId = subtitleId;
}

public String getTimeCode() {
    return timeCode;
}
public void setTimeCode(String timeCode) {
    this.timeCode = timeCode;
}
public String getOriginalSubtitleLine1() {
    return originalSubtitleLine1;
}
public void setOriginalSubtitleLine1(String originalSubtitleLine1) {
    this.originalSubtitleLine1 = originalSubtitleLine1;
}
public String getOriginalSubtitleLine2() {
    return originalSubtitleLine2;
}
public void setOriginalSubtitleLine2(String originalSubtitleLine2) {
    this.originalSubtitleLine2 = originalSubtitleLine2;
}

}
```

I did also a class SubtitleHandler.java to read the file and extract informations, like :

```
public class SubtitlesHandler {
private ArrayList<String> originalSubtitles = null;
private ArrayList<String> translatedSubtitles = null;

public SubtitlesHandler(String fileName) {
    originalSubtitles = new ArrayList<String>();
    translatedSubtitles = new ArrayList<String>();
    BufferedReader br;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            originalSubtitles.add(line);
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public ArrayList<String> getSubtitles() {
    return originalSubtitles;
}

}
```

How can I extract data from the file to build Subtitle Objects, so I can then store them in database? Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Will there always be a blank line between subtitles?  If so,  it makes things much simpler...

Comment: @KevinAnderson yes there is a blank line between each subtitle and its next.

Comment: @KevinAnderson is right. You need to keep track of some delimiter with which you can define when new subtitle information is started. It can be either a blank line or most safe bet "time". You can have a simple regex which will indicate if new subtitle entry is there or not.

Comment: @AmanBansal i tried to do a delimiter but i didn't know how because it's by line. i have before read a file by column by using delimiters but with this file built by lines, i didn't know how. do you have an example of code that can delimit this kind of files?

Comment: Read your file line by line and use a state machine to keep track of where you are. You start on state ID, then you go to state time, then state line 1 then state line 2 or blank line then back to state ID.

Comment: this is pure srt format, so try to find out good SRT parser for java

Answer (score 1):

```
    Scanner scanner=new Scanner(new File("yourfile.txt"));
    Scanner grpScanner=null;
    String id="";
    String title="";
    String subtitleLine1="";
    String subtitleLine2="";
    //split into subtitle group using empty line
    scanner.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("^\\s*$", Pattern.MULTILINE));

    //iterate subtitle group
    while(scanner.hasNext())
    {
        //store subtitle group as string
        String subgrp=scanner.next();
        //read each line in subtitle group
        grpScanner=new Scanner(subgrp);
        while(grpScanner.hasNext())
        {
            id=grpScanner.next(); //get Id
            title=grpScanner.next(); // get timecode
            subtitleLine1=grpScanner.next(); //get Subtitle_line1
            subtitleLine2=grpScanner.hasNext() ? grpScanner.next(): ""; //check for subtitle_line 2
        }
        grpScanner.close(); //close grpScanner
    }
```